# Shell command to tar directory excluding certain folders

Tags: linux, bash, backup, unix, tar

In Bash 4, I want make a `tar.gz` with excluded folders, and while tons of answers about this simple case exist, nothing works in my case.

I would like to keep the directory mentioned in exclude, perhaps I can use `exclude-tag-under`?

- I've tried:

  ```sh
  tar --exclude="www/cache" --exclude="www/wp-cache"  -vczf "/volume1/Backup/test/asdsdsd/backup104432/testeur_files_www_2023-12-12_10-36-13.tar.gz" --directory="/volume1/Backup/test/asdsdsd/" -- "www"
  ```

  Extract of verbose tar result, with the excluded directories and content still there:

  ```
  ...
  www/Marques/marque-Peugeot-logo.webp
  www/Marques/marque-Volkswagen-logo.png.webp
  www/Marques/Thumbs.db
  www/cache/
  www/cache/contact commercial PlanetVo.txt
  ```

Comment: Have you checked out the man page for [`tar`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html), or via `man tar` or `tar -?`?

Comment: @JW0914 I check tar -? and all my options are availables. Perhaps it's --exclude=PATTERN the solution ? "www/cache" is not considered as a pattern ?

Comment: Well, did you check with a glob pattern instead?

Comment: @Destroy666 Yes, and I obtain the same :
`...
www/Marques/marque-volkswagen-logo.png.webp
www/Marques/Thumbs.db
www/cache/
www/cache/contact commercial PlanetVo.txt
www/cache a conserver/
www/cache a conserver/contact commercial PlanetVo.txt
tar --exclude="**/www/cache/*" --exclude="**/www/wp-cache/*"  -vczf "/volume1/Backup/test/asdsdsd/backup104432/testeur_files_www_2023-12-12_16-18-47.tar.gz" --directory="/volume1/Backup/test/asdsdsd/" -- "www"`

Comment: Try to put the arguments in this order: `tar -vczf /.../stuff.tgz --exclude='first' --exclude='second' ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the directories at the top of each `--exclude` statement you need to exclude their content. A wildcard will match all files - including "dot" files that are normally not shown.

This should work for you. (I've pulled out your two long paths into variables only so it's a little easier to read)

```
out='/volume1/Backup/test/asdsdsd/backup104432/testeur_files_www_2023-12-12_10-36-13.tar.gz'
dir='/volume1/Backup/test/asdsdsd'

tar -cvzf "$out" -C "$dir" --exclude='www/cache/*' --exclude='www/wp-cache/*' www
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right; the order makes a difference here, and now it works. Thanks again for your help.